# Is there some way to recover Eclipse IDE extra used memory?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, swap

on what Eclipse uses so much extra memory? could it be a bug?

on starting eclipse IDE Oxigen rc2/rc3, it uses about 600mb of ram.

after about 30h non stop using it (suspended the notebook many times in between, without closing eclipse). It raises to 2.5Gb.

a few more hours it will be about 3.2Gb and then the machine memory will end and will start swapping making everything slow requiring restart eclipse, that will be 600Mb again.

eclipse's heap garbage collector does nothing, wont help on that.

any preferences option or startup commandline java options that could help on eclipse releasing some of that memory? if it remained in about 1Gb it would help a lot. using jdk 8 here.

ini file useful info (none of these helps btw):

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

edit: at oxygen RC3, the trashcan worked from 2.3GB to 1.9GB. Before I be sure, I will keep rc3 open for many days and see if it will continue working well with the trashcan click. Til now is working as I needed!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3776478/967768 ?

Comment: @SebLemieux that answer is what makes no difference here, but I will read the other things there to try them if any solves it thx

Comment: You tried to add the .ini parameters mentioned in there? And you tried to click the thrashcan button ?

Comment: @SebLemieux that topic is too old, for java6, I tried another option that isnt there, -xincgc something like that, and eclipse simply wouldnt run until I removed it from the ini file, I wonder if there is some updated info about what can be done? I will show its ini file, xms xmx already there makes no difference either :(

Comment: @SebLemieux clicked the trashcan many times, didnt help, I confirm memory used at linux system monitor. xms xmx already at ini, makes no diff either. I show some more stuff at ini file, none helps, thats the default ini file btw. anything beyond that I could do?

Comment: Maybe someone else will but I can't. I switched to IntelliJ to stop worrying about that a while ago.

Comment: @SebLemieux oh ok thx, intellij is too slow and heavy here, eclipse runs quite smooth, but I have to reopen it from time to time heh

Comment: You're using rc version. Have you tried to use stable?

Comment: @AleksandrM no oxygen stable to the date http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/all, I think there may have a way to limit the amount of used memory/resources on linux only using cgroups, have to try yet tho. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125024/235896

Comment: @VeganEye Yep, but there is Neon.